# Что значит ошибка php: "Cannot send session cache limiter"?

Tags: php

> `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Y:\home\localhost\www\u\parent.php:2) in Y:\home\localhost\www\u\parent.php on line 3`

Answer (score 1):

Где то выше session_start() что-то выводишь. Нехорошо так делать. Стартовать сессию нужно до какого либо вывода echo и др.

Comment: да  нет) у меня в самом начале

Comment: А пробел/перенос строки до `<?` есть?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что есть... ^.^